# relationship between View-model and Model and View

Tags: mvvm

I was reading about MVVM and it seems there is a one to many relationship between view-model and the model classes.

1. Is it OK to say one model-view must be used for different Model classes in a project?
2. How about View to View-Model relationship? would it make sense to use one View-Model to handle more than one View?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The Model in "Model -View -ViewModel" is your data structure where you create the objects you will be working with both in the view and the viewModel. Models can be used everywhere. You will use many models on many different viewModels.

The View uses one ViewModel. The View is responsible for the appearance. The view references its one viewModel through the DataContext property. It can be set in the XAML or in the constructor of the code behind of the view.

The ViewModel encapsulates the presentation logic and has no direct reference to the view.